# Bash script calls expect script with master SSH connection

Tags: bash, ssh, scp, ssh-tunneling, expect

I'm trying to write a `bash` script that calls an `expect` script to establish a master SSH connection to be used for the remaining SSH commands in the bash script.

~/.ssh/config:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p
```

upload.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

expect -f /home/Dave/bin/ssh.exp

scp /home/Dave/bin/test root@192.168.1.1:/root/test

ssh root@192.168.1.1 "echo 'Test' >> /root/test"

ssh -O exit root@192.168.1.1
```

ssh.exp:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Enable some diagnostic output
exp_internal 1

spawn /usr/bin/ssh -M -N root@192.168.1.1

expect {
    -re ".*yes.*no.*" {
        exp_send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    -re ".*password.*" {
        exp_send "OMGSECRET\r"
    }
}

$ bin/upload.sh
spawn /usr/bin/ssh -M -N root@192.168.1.1
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {5212}
Gate keeper glob pattern for '.*yes.*no.*' is ''. Not usable, disabling the performance booster.
Gate keeper glob pattern for '.*password.*' is '*password*'. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression ".*yes.*no.*"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no
".*password.*"? Gate "*password*"? gate=no
root@192.168.1.1's password:
expect: does "root@192.168.1.1's password: " (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression ".*yes.*no.*"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no
".*password.*"? Gate "*password*"? gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "root@192.168.1.1's password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "root@192.168.1.1's password: "
send: sending "OMGSECRET\r" to { exp4 }
mux_client_request_session: read from master failed: Connection reset by peer
root@192.168.1.1's password:
root@192.168.1.1's password:
```

The SSH connection is being established, but it craps out when I try to reuse it for the SCP command. Why?

Possible final sad edit: Alas it appears [cygwin doesn't support multiplexing](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-08/msg00072.html).

Comment: Are you sure that the password is correct and that the server accepts root login with a password? Does it work if you aren't using the expect script?

Comment: Where will the user be typing the password? Why not run the master ssh command in a terminal and make the user enter the password there?

Comment: **Do not the password on the command line.** It can be snooped by other users if they run `ps` at the right time. It's safe to pass the password in an environment variable (`$::env(PASSWORD)` in Tcl).

Comment: I'm sure the password is correct and I can log in from terminal with those credentials. The user enters the password in a web form (PHP), then the server passes the password to the bash script. Since the user doesn't see the terminal window, I can't have them enter the password there.

Comment: @Gilles I removed all mention of PHP from the question. For now, I just want to get this to work from the console.

Answer (score 4):

Using an Expect script to send a hard-coded plaintext password is generally a Very Bad Idea.  If you needs scriptable, passwordless SSH connections, it's far better to use key-pair authentication:

```
ssh-keygen # and then follow the prompts; don't set a passphrase
ssh-copy-id username@remote.host.example.com
```

After doing so, you can `ssh user@remote.host.example.com` without needing to key in your password.

You can still use the control connection muxing set up with the `Control` directives in `~/.ssh/config`, and close the master connection with `ssh -O exit user@remote.host.example.com`.

You ought also to use `ssh`'s utility of simply running commands remotely - once you have key-pair authentication set up, you can have:

```
ssh username@remote.host.exameple.com /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

in your script and be all set to go.

Comment: Who said password was hard coded? It's prompted from the user (which is btw a requirement).

Comment: In the example bash script, it's metasyntactically set on the first line after the shebang:  `# Set $user, $addr, $pass, $source and $dest ...`

Comment: It's an argument passed to the script though. Is that okay?

Comment: It's still exposing the password in plain text to anyone who manages to read your bash script.  Private keys are never set group- or world-readable and allow many layers of additional security.  For example, if your key is compromised, you can remove it from the remote host's `authorized-keys` file and generate a new keypair without having to worry about resetting your password.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify: this script is called from an app that prompts the user for a password. I don't understand at what point it becomes plain text, unless the `expect -f upload.exp "$user" "$addr" "$pass"` part is logged somewhere with the actual password?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  If you are having the user enter the password in real time, that actually eliminates the need for using the `expect` script at all; simply have the user enter the password normally.  Otherwise, unless you're taking measures, the password *will* be exposed in plaintext on-screen when the user enters the password for the purposes of populating the `pass` variable unless you use `read -s` or some other mechanism that disables remote echo.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12260/discussion-between-davidkennedy85-and-dopeghoti)

Answer (score 0):

if this is still your question:

> "The SSH connection is being established, but it craps out when I try
>   to reuse it for the SCP command. Why?"

This happens because you are starting a seperate shell with your expect script. Your ssh session is bound to this shell and if your script ends the shell also end and your ssh session dies.

Sorry but I don't have a solution in a nutshell for this problem.